# yammer feed does not scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yammer

have a yammer feed put in as one of the divs in my html page. Everything works fine and yammer feeds loads in fine.

But the yammer feed is frozen to the specified height on page load and does not have a scroll bar. In order to get the scroll bar. I need to log out using the link in the widget and log back in using the embed component pop-up. Then the scroll bar appears.

If the div style display:none; is removed from the line `<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:900px;width:700px;display:none;" align="left">`,, then it works fine.

I have tried to look for fixes and was not able to get any answer. Is there a fix for this. Is there a way to make the yammer feed shows a login button like in the picture on page load by default on page load.

Currently I have to manually logout using the logout link in the widget to get the login button. I was wondering if its possible to get it by default on page load.

```js
yam.connect.embedFeed({
  "network": "<compnay network>",
  "feedType": "group",
  "feedId": <feed id>,
  "config": {
    "use_sso": false,
    "header": true,
    "footer": true,
    "showOpenGraphPreview": false,
    "defaultToCanonical": false,
    "hideNetworkName": false
  },
  "container": "#embedded-feed"
});

$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var divname= this.name;
    $("#"+divname).fadeIn("slow").siblings().fadeOut("fast");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" name="div100" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item1</font></a>
<a href="#" name="div200" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item2</font></a>
<a href="#" name="div300" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item3</font></a>
<a href="#" name="div400" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">item4</font></a>
<a href="#" name="embedded-feed" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ><font color = "white">Yammer feed</font></a>

<div id="div100" style="display:none" align="left">
<li1><a href="#" name="div1" >item1-desc1</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div2" >item1-desc2</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div3" >item1-desc3</a></li1>
  
<div id="div200" style="display:none" align="left">
<li1><a href="#" name="div4" > item2-desc1</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div5" >item2-desc2</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div6" >item2-desc3</a></li1>
    
<div id="div300" style="display:none" align="left">
<li1><a href="#" name="div7" > item3-desc1</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div8" >item3-desc2</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div9" >item3-desc3</a></li1>
      
<div id="div400" style="display:none" align="left">
<li1><a href="#" name="div10" > item4-desc1</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div11" >item4-desc2</a></li1>
<li1><a href="#" name="div12" >item4-desc3</a></li1>
  
<div id="div1" style="display:none" align="left">
  <!--div1 contents-->
<div id="div2" style="display:none" align="left">
  <!--div2 contents-->
<div id="div3" style="display:none" align="left">
  <!--div3 contents-->
<div id="div4" style="display:none" align="left">
  <!--div4 contents-->
<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:900px;width:700px;display:none;" align="left">
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading"> <center><h3>YAMMER FEED</h3><p><font color = red> If the feed is frozen, click on the logout link below and log back in.</font></p></center><br></div>
 </div>
 </div>  
  <!--- so on... -->


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/platform_embed.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `display:none;`?  It seems you have that on the parent div anyway..

Comment: I tried that but did not hide the yammer feed on page load. I have another idea now. I will try to add a clear function on page load and add a display back function to the link that triggers the yammer div. I will post the results shortly.

Comment: @rawfocus. I have tried the idea. I removed the `display:none;` and tried to hide the div on page load and appear back on click, but the header appears until the allow block content is clicked and then hides. Also after all this, the yammer feed does not have the scroll bar. I need to manually log out from the feed and log back in to get the scroll bar.